# How to do formatted printing in MIPS

Tags: mips

How to translate the following/equivalant C programming line in MIPS?

```
printf("This number is: %d, that number is: %d", int1, int2);
```

Comment: @Michael With C standard library.

Answer (score 1):

use syscall
print string is where you set $v0 to 4
double is 3, integer is 1

```
toPrint: .asciiz "This number is:"
toPrint1: .asciiz ", that number is"

li $vo, 4 #print string
la $a0, toPrint
syscall
li $v0, 5 #read int1
syscall
add $a0, $v0, $zero
li $v0, 1 # print int1
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, toPrint1 # load string to print
syscall
li $v0, 5# read int2 #user put number in console
syscall
add $a0, $v0, $zero
li $v0, 1 # print int2
li $v0, 10# exit
syscall
```